# Lagrange's Theorem on sum of four squares.

Tags: number-theory

It is well known that a positive rational number is a sum of four squares. The Gaussian integers generalize the rational integers. What can be said about the decomposition of a gaussian integer in sum of squares of gaussian integers?

Comment: For a start, every square has even imaginary part, so anything with odd imaginary part is not a sum of squares.

Comment: A related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/14456/sum-of-squares-in-ring-of-integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/99/sum2squares) for a proof that every $a+2bi$ with $a$ odd is a sum of $2$ squares, with $a$ even, a sum of three squares.

Ivan Niven, Integers of quadratic fields as sums of squares, Transactions of the AMS 1940, proves that in an imaginary quadratic field every integer $a+2b\sqrt{-m}$ is a sum of three squares. He starts with the Gaussians. The paper should be freely available at the AMS website.